# Why different bra ket notations?

Tags: math-mode, braket

Why are bra and ket defined in the official package [`braket.sty`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/braket) in two different ways (`\bra`, `\Bra` and `\ket`, `\Ket`)?

I do not understand why there exists the command `\bra` with non-scalable delimiters. For stylistic reasons, I intuitively used the capital letter versions. Were you ever confronted with the second non-scalable version?

See the short example for bra:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Bra{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\uparrow + \downarrow\right)}
  &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\Bra{\uparrow}+\Bra{\downarrow}\right)\\
\bra{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\uparrow + \downarrow\right)}
  &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\bra{\uparrow}+\bra{\downarrow}\right)\\
&=2 222 22\\
&=2\mathinner{222}22
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

#### Understanding of the package's definition

For amsmath noobs like myself, the last two lines in the align environment review what `\mathinner` does (if you look at the [`braket.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/braket/braket.sty)'s package source code). The package defined the commands the following way:

```
\def\bra#1{\mathinner{\langle{#1}|}}
\def\ket#1{\mathinner{|{#1}\rangle}}
\def\Bra#1{\left\langle#1\right|}
\def\Ket#1{\left|#1\right\rangle}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the package (I'm not saying it is bad at all, I just wouldn't use it); I would define my own macros as done [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140766/defining-a-new-function-with-argument-in-latex-environment/140770#140770).

Comment: What is the advantage of using `mathtools`' command `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` for the delimiters? You cannot apply user-defined scaling like `\Bigg` either (you wrote about it in your answer below).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The macros with uppercase initial are "self-expanding" based on the contents, as the documentation says. Just like it's not good to always use `\left` and `\right`, it's also good to choose with care between `\Bra` and `\bra`.

As far as the additional spacing is concerned, a solution is to load `mleftright`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket,mleftright}
\mleftright

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Bra{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\uparrow + \downarrow\right)}
  &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\Bra{\uparrow}+\Bra{\downarrow}\right)\\
\bra{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\uparrow + \downarrow\right)}
  &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\bra{\uparrow}+\bra{\downarrow}\right)\\
&=2 222 22\\
&=2\mathinner{222}22\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you use `mleftright`? Stylistic question: Were you ever confronted with the non-scalable version?

Comment: @strpeter `\mleftright` redefines `\left` and `\right` to use the "non spaced" version (that is, to `\mleft` and `\mright` respectively). I never use bra-ket notation myself: I do algebra, you know. `;-)`

Comment: @strpeter, if you have `\sum_{i}` inside an automatic scaling \left and \right, the delimiters scale to the wrong height.

Answer (score 6):

Generically speaking the `\left<delim> ... \right<delim>` are used to fit the height of the content with expandable delimiters, chosen to by higher than all parts of the content.

But it is well-known that this choice often produce too large (tall) delimiters, and must be avoided for aesthetic reasons (and resulting typographic rules), as tactfully said by egreg and as exemplified by  Aditya's comment. It's better practice to keep the delimiters height as small as possible, provided they ensure good readability.

That is why I don't use `braket.sty` but my own `.sty` based on `\big` and `\Big`, and some trick related to old-fashion `\def` with e.g. for the bras:

```
\def\bra<#1|{\langle #1\rvert}
\def\Bra<#1|{\big\langle #1\big\rvert}
\def\BRA<#1|{\Big\langle #1\Big\rvert}
```

and I would code the example discussed here:

```
\BRA<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\uparrow + \downarrow\right)|
    =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\bra<\uparrow|+\bra<\downarrow|\big)
```

the result of which, is IMO, better looking than the `braket.sty` result as coded by strpeter and posted by egreg. 
[image: Bra with \Big] 

As  further comments:

- it would typeset the fraction in `\textstyle` to avoid to give him the emphasize
- the left hand side is not a really meaningful notation for this state

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are here to type bra-ket notation for Markdown or web applications, you can try the following method:

```
$$
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left \langle #1 \right \rvert}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left \rvert #1 \right \rangle}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\left \langle #1 \right \rangle}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left \langle #1 \middle \rvert #2 \right \rangle}
\newcommand{\braxket}[3]{\left \langle #1 \middle \rvert #2 \middle \rvert #3 \right \rangle}

\bra{\Psi}, \;
\ket{\varphi}, \;
\E{\frac{\Psi^\dag\Psi}{2/3}}, \;
\braket{\frac{\Psi}{2/3}}{\varphi}, \;
\braxket{\frac{\Psi}{2/3}}{A}{\varphi}
$$
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you would use `\left \rvert`.  I would expect `\left \lvert` (or ever `\left \vert`).

Comment: I agree with Barbara, try `\braket{1}{-1}` the - 1 will have the wrong spacing. (though not sure if middle changes anything)