# Defining a new function with argument and angular brackets

Tags: macros

I want to define a function in a LaTeX document. More precisely, I want to define a function, say `\ang{x}`, where `x` is any input, such that the output is `\rangle x \langle`. Is there a way to go about this using `\newcommand`, or any way at all, for that matter?

Comment: Happy to be here!

Comment: I sincerely apologize for it taking me so long!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I normally use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) for something like this. The point is that with the starred version, the delimiters automatically scale.

You can use a lot of different brackets, and you can make the macro take multiple arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\inner[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1,#2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set{\lbrace}{\rbrace}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \bra{a}       &= \bra*{\frac{a}{1}}\\
  \ket{a}       &= \ket*{\frac{a}{1}}\\
  \braket{a}{b} &= \braket*{\frac{a}{1}}{\frac{b}{1}}\\
  \inner{a}{b}  &= \inner*{\frac{a}{1}}{\frac{b}{1}}\\
  \abs{a}       &= \abs*{\frac{a}{1}}\\
  \norm{a}      &= \norm*{\frac{a}{1}}\\
  \set{a,b}     &= \set*{\frac{a}{1},\frac{b}{1}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: @Gottfried: All this stuff is provided by the »[physics](http://ctan.org/pkg/physics)« package.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I could be missing something, but I don't see the _automatic_ scaling of delimiters in the manual.

Comment: The complete Section 2 shows automatic scaling.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig It  seems that using the `physics` package will result in very poor spacing.

Comment: I like how you defined practically every common delimiter command *except* the one that was requested. 

Answer (score 25):

A straightforward way to define such a macro would be

```
\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
```

If you need the sizes of the angle brackets to grow with the size of the argument, you might want to define `\ang` as

```
\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\mleft\langle #1 \mright\rangle}
```

where `\mleft` and `\mright` are macros provided by the [mleftright](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package. Using `\mleft` and `\mright` instead of `\left` and `\right` has certain advantages, specifically in terms of the whitespace padding that would be inserted by TeX.

Either way, `\ang` takes one argument, which will be typeset surrounded by left-hand and right-hand angle brackets.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: This is good/correct/..., but I perfer `mathtool`'s solution; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140770/15874.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - I'm aware of the `mathtools` package and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro. The OP was asking specifically for a solution using `\newcommand` -- presumably in part so that he/she could learn how to use this method -- so that's why I provided a solution that involves only `\newcommand` and no additional package. :-)

Comment: I have a feeling that this is because the OP wasn't aware of the other possibility. To quote a part of the question "...or any way at all, for that matter". `:)`

Comment: Well, I was not aware of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, and I reasoned that `\newcommand` must be the way. Both answers solved my inquiry, needless to say!

Comment: You might want to replace `\left...\right` by either `\mleft...\mright` from the `mleftright` package or an equivalent construction. (Or discourage the use of automatic scaling altogether. )

Comment: @Gaussler - Thanks for this suggestion, which I've happily implemented.

Answer (score 18):

You might want to have a look at the [`bropd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bropd) package.

It features the `br{}` command that is a little more advanced. I matches the size of the brackets and automatically uses round, square, or curly brackets.

```
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{2}\br{f\cdot\br{x \br{y+z} + \br{\frac{a}{b}+c} }+g}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat! I wasn't aware of this package. Does it "do" angle brackets as well?

Comment: Yeah, one of my favorite packages. No more forgetting closing your brackets! The features for differentials are also a huge timesaver, especially when typesetting stuff like thermodynamics.

It doesn't feature angle brackets. I have actually never seen them as a way to structure equations but rather as a way to denote the mean of a quantity.