# Typeset < > symbol

Tags: symbols

I am trying to typeset this < P > by writing it in math-mode using the symbols <> of the keypad. The problem is that the output in ugly. How can I typeset it so to have a nice output?

Comment: `$\langle P\rangle$`

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140766/defining-a-new-function-with-argument-in-latex-environment

Comment: Define “ugly”. What is wrong with the rendering? Also define “nice”. And are you sure you should be using math mode? It looks like you might be trying to display HTML tags.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thank you! As for the HTML I am not trying to display such a thing that is for sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the angular parenthesis `\langle` and `\rangle`.
In your case you have to write `$\langle P \rangle$`.

If you add `\left\langle P \right\rangle` they'll come out in the perfect size.

Hope this help!