# Autosizing for expectation with additional index

Tags: math-mode, macros, mathtools

I was trying to define a new command for an expectation which scales the vertical dash (in case of conditional expectation) and parenthesis to the argument, respectively. Additionally, I want to have a parameter which specifies which expectation I am talking about, i.e. $\mathbb{E}_{index}$ where index an arbitrary value.

I was following the instruction from this post [[vertical bar for absolute value and conditional expectation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187162/vertical-bar-for-absolute-value-and-conditional-expectation][here]). Unfortunately, the index is now the argument of the expectation and the other way around. When simply exchanging #1 with #2, I get a missing number error.

The code I am using:

```
\newcommand{\expcti}[2]{\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}_{#2}\expectiarg#1}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\expectiarg}[1]{[}{]}{%
  \ifnum\currentgrouptype=16 \else\begingroup\fi
  \activatebar#1
  \ifnum\currentgrouptype=16 \else\endgroup\fi
}


\newcommand{\innermid}{\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\;}
\newcommand{\activatebar}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\|
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\innermid 
  \mathcode`|=\string"8000
}
```

I am happy about any help here. Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**

What I am trying to achieve is a command which automatically scales the vertical bar in a conditional expectation with the parentheses, i.e. left what I get when simply using `\left[` and `\right]` and right what I actually want:

[image]

I'd like to achieve the formula on the r.h.s. by typing `$$\expcti*{\frac{1}{2} | Y}{F}$$`

Comment: Could you post  a sketch of what you're trying to achieve? As is, it's not very clear.

Comment: @Bernahrd Thanks for pointing out, I just added an example of what I am trying to achieve. Is it clear now?

Comment: I see. I think one of the variants of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` can do it. *Unrelated*: the formula would look nicer with  `\mfrac{1}{2}` (it is the medium-size fraction command from `nccmath`).

Comment: I think the problem lies in the first line of code. the \expcti command should not be affected by the index. I just want the operator to use the second argument as an index. Thanks for the side note, did not know about this.

Comment: I think I've provided a simpler code in my answer, with the help of `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP`.

Comment: Great thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, using two arguments: the index and the random variables, separated by a `|`. If you want no index, use an empty argument. If tere is no conditional part,, i.e. if you type no `|`, no vertical rule will be printed. If you need to use one in your formula which shouldn't be interpreted as a separator, use `{|}` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, nccmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Expect[2]{\mathbb{E}_{#1}}[]{}{\setargs{#2}}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\expectaux[3]{\mathbb{E}_{#1}}[]{}{#2\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:#3}%

\begin{document}

\[ \Expect*{i}{\mfrac{1}{2}X | Y} \quad\Expect[\bigg]{k}{\mfrac{1}{2}X} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]